# In my code, why is lack of a function declaration a non-issue for one function, but throws a warning for another?

Tags: c

In the following program,I use two functions prd() and display().I have declared neither of them ahead of main() before invoking them in main(),and I have defined both after main().Yet while prd() works smoothly inside main(),invoking display() shows the warning   " previous implicit declaration of 'display' was here ".What is different about display() that there is a warning for it but not for the other funciton prd()?I have declared neither of them to begin with.Still there is warning due to invocation of one, but other one works fine.

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int x=8,y=11;

        printf("The product of %d & %d is %d",x,y,prd(x,y));

        display();

        return 0;
    }

    int prd(int x,int y)
    {
        return x*y;
    }

    void display()
    {
        printf("\n Good Morning");
    }
```

PS: And I would really appreciate if you can answer this secondary question --"Is function declaration not necessary at all in C provided there is a definition for it?".I have the habit of declaring all functions of the program before the main() function, and then defining them after the main() function.Am I wrong?

Comment: Sidenote: `int main()` is **NOT** a proper declaration providing a prototype in C (unlike C++). It is old-style, deprecated K&R style, saying that main takes an unspecified but fixed number of args. Use `int main(void)` for now until eternity.

Comment: Oh,I will definitely keep that in mind.I had been cautioned about it before but since my compiler never had a problem with it I didn't bother.Will I get into problem if I use something that is deprecated?Will it show error/warning in C99 mode of codeblocks?

Comment: @Jens I had messaged you seconds before you made your comment.It's about another question of mine, the one about recursion that you answered.I want to know if any number like x^23 can be expressed as x^16 * x^4 * x^2 * x^1 (each power being a square root of preceding power till it is 1).Your formula I understood, but another user Cobbal has that formula.

Comment: You'll get a warning for `int main()` with `gcc -Wstrict-prototypes` saying `warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype`. Adding `-Werror` turns it into an error.

Comment: @Jens I have the utter misfortune that I am unfamiliar with Linux and  with compiling from the command prompt.So kindly tell me concisely if "-Werro" is an option we can add while compiling with gcc from the command prompt?Is it?What does it mean?And in a nutshell, what is gcc-Wstrict-prototypes?I feel miserable that I don't know even this much.

Comment: Both `-Wstrict-prototypes` and `-Werror` are gcc options. The first checks if you stricly use prototypes, and the latter turns all warnings into errors. Yes, both options can be added to your compile command. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options

Comment: @Jens Thanks a lot.It was nice of you!

Comment: Please note I am a different Jens than the one you referred to above (my avatar is the HAL9000 eye).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use undeclared `display()` the compiler implicitly declares it as if it were returning `int`.

When the compiler finally sees the definition of `display()`, it sees that the return type is `void`, but it's already assumed it be `int` and so the definition and the implicit declaration differ, hence the error/warning.

Answer (score 4):

The error occurs because C considers all non-initiated functions with a return type of `int`. Your `display` function is later defined with `void` return type.

Changing the return type of `display()` to `int` removes the warning.

Answer (score 2):

By default, compiler assumes non-declared functions as returning `int`.

This is true for your `prd` function, but it does not match with `display()` as its `void`. This causes compiler to raise a warning.

For 2nd, its always appropriate to declare functions.