# Can the pre-processor directives like #include be placed only at the top of the program code?

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor, pragma, preprocessor-directive

I have used the `#pragma` directive inside functions without error or warning(especially `#pragma pack()`).But the following code shows the warning `incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf'|`:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("Trial");
}

#include<stdio.h>
```

Further, here's is an extract from a book I have.The author has bad reviews on SO,especially for his generous use of `void main()`,but still I feel no author can be **that** bad to claim the following without reason:

> Each of these preprocessor directives begin with a # 
>   symbol. The directives can be placed anywhere in a program but 
>   are most often placed at the beginning of a program, before the 
>   first function definition.

So can you tell me whether it's mandatory to use some preprocessor directives like `#include` at the top of the program while others like `#pragma` can be used anywhere in the program?

**Edit** After **OUAH**'s remark I tried the following, but it doesn't give warning,it gives a big pile of **errors**.LOL.

```
int main(void)
{
    #include<stdio.h>
    printf("Trial");
}
```

Comment: `#include` directives for standard headers may only be included at file scope — not inside functions.  ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.1.2 **Standard headers**, ¶4 ... _If
used, a header shall be included outside of any external declaration or definition, and it
shall first be included before the first reference to any of the functions or objects it
declares, or to any of the types or macros it defines._ ...  Note that this restriction only applies to standard headers; you can write headers of your own that can be placed anywhere (if you're careful).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `#include` directive can be placed anywhere in a source file, but in C an identifier can  usually not be used before it has been declared. That's the reason why you put the `#include` directive at the begining of your source file.

```
void foo(void)
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
}

extern int printf(const char *, ...);  // Error, the declaration should be put 
                                       // before the actual call
```

Comment: So can we use `#include` inside the main() function right before we use `printf()` to deal with the warning?Will it be ok?

Comment: Look at the edit to my question.It generates a pile of errors.

Comment: I tried using `#include` before using `printf()`, but inside `main(0`.It gives a big pile of errors.But if I use `#pragma` the same way, it shows no warning or error.Why?

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture the errors are not related to the fact an include directive is put inside a function, but because you are expected to use this particular header file at file-scope. Try with an empty `file.h` header file and you could see you can include it anywhere in the program file.

Comment: But still,isn't `printf()` supposed to work in your code above?After all in C when a function is not declared, it is assumed to return `int`.Look at this following question which I had posted.The function `prd()` clearly doesn't need any function declaration as long its return type is `int`.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756196/in-my-code-why-is-lack-of-a-function-declaration-a-non-issue-for-one-function    How would you explain that?That contradicts your above code,which seems to say `printf()` won't work just because it doesn't have a declaration!!

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture Since C99, the rule from implicit declaration has been removed. In C89 this is also not supposed to work as the implicit declaration of `printf` would be `int printf();` but this declaration is correct only for non-variadic functions.

Comment: Thanks.Never knew it doesn't apply to variadic functions.

Answer (score 6):

Think of it this way. The content of the included file is simply inserted at the point in the file where the #include directive appears. The resulting code needs to be syntactically correct for the language that you are programming in.

Confider the following file:

```
int a;

int foo();

int main()
#include "myheader.h"

int foo()
{
    return 0;
}
```

And the file myheader.h contains:

```
{
    return foo();
}
```

The code that the compiler will see after the preprocessor has processed the #include directive is:

```
int a;

int foo();

int main()
{
    return foo();
}

int foo()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This is valid C syntax. Such use of the #include directive is not recommended, but it gives you an idea of what it means. If the myheader.h file had the following content:

```
this is some garbage
which is not proper C
```

Then the resulting code will be:

```
int a;

int foo();

int main()
this is some garbage
which is not proper C

int foo()
{
    return 0;
}
```

You can use #include at any point in the file. It results in literal inclusion of the content of the included file at that point. The reason you get a undeclared message for printf() in your code is that C requires a function be declared before use, and stdio.h has that declaration. Which is why it needs to be before it's use. And why it cannot be included in main() in the latter example is because on inclusion (expansion), it results in syntactically incorrect C code.

Answer (score 0):

"#pragma" directive will be ignored by C compiler since it considers the lines with "#" tag as comments. Looks like you are using openmp. The OpenMP compiler considers these(#pragma) as parallel directives. Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  What you've said is, I'm afraid, completely wrong.  ISO/IEC 9899:2011, §6.10.6 **Pragma directive** says _A preprocessing directive of the form
`# pragma pp-tokens.opt new-line`
where the preprocessing token STDC does not immediately follow pragma_ ... _If the preprocessing token STDC does immediately follow pragma_ ...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Can you confirm Mr.Jonathan that in **no cirumstance** the compiler considers lines beginning with `#` as comments?

Comment: @Rüppell'sVulture: I believe it is correct to say the the C preprocessor never considers a `#` as starting a comment.  You can have an empty (null) preprocessor directive (a `#` followed by a newline); you can have a `#` that's not noticed by the preprocessor (there are rules on when a `#` is detected by the preprocessor); the compiler will ignore directives it does not recognize (_Any such
pragma that is not recognized by the implementation is ignored._).  But I don't think there are any circumstances under which the `#` symbol introduces what is formally treated as a comment.

Comment: I was talking about #pragma directives. Directives follow conventions of the C/C++ standards for compiler directives. When compiled with the C compiler, it's just a serial program and the compiler doesn't throw any error.