# How to understand a #include inside a enum definition?

Tags: c

How do I interpret this C code:

```
typedef enum {
    #include <test.h>
    enum1,
    enum2,
    …
} test_enum;
```

test.h includes many macros. How to understand this?

Does means that the definitions of the enum needs the macros defined inside the header file?

Can `#include` appear anywhere?

Comment: `#include` is basically "copy paste this code here"

Answer (score 6):

An `#include` statement may appear on any line. It is most often used to include entire declarations. However, it can be used to insert any text.

It may be that `test.h` contains a list of names to be declared inside the `enum`. It may also contain preprocessor statements, such as macro definitions or `#if … #endif` statements.

You would have to show the contents of `test.h` for further help understanding it.

Answer (score 2):

`#include` and `#define` are **pre processor directives** not actual code.

You can put them anywhere (except as part of a literal string) - some compilers are more fussy than others (i.e. the # has to be in column 0).

The Preprocessor expands these out as required, and that is what the compiler sees. As to what it means in your case, depends on the content of test.h

There is normally a compiler option to see your code with all the preprocessor stuff expanded (used to be -e or -E on gcc I think)

Answer (score 2):

The #include directive causes the contents of the included file to be placed exactly at the point of the #include directive. The resulting code is what it is once that expansion has taken place, and can be any valid language construct.

If the included file contains:

```
enum_a,
enum_b,
enum_c,
```

Then after inclusion, your code would look like:

```
typedef enum {
    enum_a,
    enum_b,
    enum_c,
    enum1,
    enum2,
    …
} test_enum;
```

Which is a valid construct.

A #include directive can appear anywhere. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389126/can-the-pre-processor-directives-like-include-be-placed-only-at-the-top-of-the/16389524#16389524).

Answer (score 0):

Pre-processor statements can occur anywhere and are simple textual substitutions. Whether or not the processed code is valid C code is checked by the compiler, not the pre-processor.

Depending on your compiler you can review the changes done by the pre-processor.

For gcc, this would be the `-E` flag, so by compiling your source code with

```
gcc -E in.c
```

you can see which changes code is contained in the enum declaration after inserting `test.h` and
processing it.